# how to get value from tables if condition is satisfied in this way

Tags: mysql, case

My query is shown below - But MySql alerts the error message. How would I resolve this?

```
IF (prdct_id = 3) THEN
SELECT prdct_det_id Product Id
       prdct_det_desc Product Name
       prdct_ref_pct  WebShare Percent
FROM   ema_prdct_det ;
END IF;
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Kindly try to ask clearly with understand column values. It will be better to understand the site expert.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (prdct_id = 3) THEN
SELECT prdct_det_id `Product Id`
   prdct_det_desc `Product Name`
   prdct_ref_pct  `WebShare Percent`
FROM ema_prdct_det ;
END IF;`
```

You have error in syntax. 
When you are using space in alias for any column then apostrophe is must to use.

Comment: backtic, double-quote, or apostrophe -- any will work for an alias